# Strange issue with loading an UIImage from core dara directly using KVC

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am in the middle of an app project with core data where I stricty use KVC only with regard to the `NSManagedObjects`. The purpose of consequentally doing that is simply to get an understanding of advantages and disadvanages. I may have discovered a disadvangate. However, I cannot explain why.

I came across this when I used some very well established principle (used that in other apps already) of saving a scetch that the user drew with his fingers (a signature to a document) in core data and fetch and display or print to PDF respectively it later.

It turned out that I was able to get the `UIImage` from the view, store it in core data and instanly receive it from core data again using KVC (no save/fetch in between) and display it in another view for testing purposes. But I was unable to actually save it, fetch the data from persistant storage and re-display it on the screen. 
So I did a lot of debugging, analysed the sqlite file etc. Eventually I nailed it down to the following strange behaviour:

Situation: 
The image was stored into core data successfully by doing this:

```
[self.detailItem setValue:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:kSignatureImage];
```

with `image` being an `UIImage` object and `self.detailItem` is the `NSManagedOBject`. Keys and references and everything is fine.

Then it comes to displaying the view again. The following is independent from whether the context was saved in between or even the app was closed and restartet or not:

```
self.signatureCanvas.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.detailTextLabel valueForKey:kSignatureImage]];
```

with `self.signatureCanvas` beeing an `UIImageView` subclass object. The image is not shown on screen.

```
NSData *data = [self.detailItem valueForKey:kSignatureImage];

NSLog(@"UIImage   a: %@", [UIImage imageWithData:[self.detailTextLabel valueForKey:kSignatureImage]]);
NSLog(@"UIImage   b: %@", [UIImage imageWithData:data]);

self.testImage.image =  [UIImage imageWithData:[self.detailTextLabel valueForKey:kSignatureImage]];

self.signatureCanvas.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

`self.testImage` is a second plain UIImageView withn the same view (but smaller). Now the image is visible in `signatureCanvas` but not in `testImage`. (could be vice versa, tried that)

The output give a hint on what was happening but no actual explanation:

```
2013-03-22 12:43:37.746 MyApp[1595:c07] UIImage   a: (null)
2013-03-22 12:43:37.769 MyApp[1595:c07] UIImage   b: <UIImage: 0x7c973a0>
```

Until now I would have thought that the lines of code were kinda equivalent and that the compiler may even optimize the data object away. But why is the image `(null)` in one case and not in the other.

So I found the problem root cause and a workaround. Therefore this is not urgent any more. But I do not understand it. Any clues?

Environment is: SDK 6.1, xcode 4.6, ARC, core data on sqlite, iPad only so far. All this happens in a UITableViewCell subclass (prototype cell within storyboard) naturally in a UITableViewController subclass.

Comment: Core Dara is always strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `self.detailTextLabel` in

```
self.testImage.image =  [UIImage imageWithData:[self.detailTextLabel valueForKey:kSignatureImage]];
```

should be `self.detailItem`.

Comment: Embarrasing that is. Yes, that was the problem. I spent ages on debugging and overlooked that. Anyway this comes certainly on the down side of using KVC vs proper model classes.